# Android LiveData Observer after onPause

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-jetpack

The problem is next, I subscribed to `LiveData` changes in activity and the first time I'm getting all data in the observer, but when I start another activity and then return to this, the observer not called.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(MainMenuViewModel.class);

    observeViewModel();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    viewModel.loadUserEntry();
}


public void observeViewModel() {

    viewModel.getUser().observe(this, userEntry -> {

        // Do some code 
    });
}
```

here is code of my ViewModel

```
void loadUserEntry() {

    disposable.add(userRepository.getUser()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(user::setValue, Throwable::printStackTrace));

}

public LiveData<UserEntry> getUser() {
    return user;
}
```

So I tested and all-time in subscribe I have user value and then I'm setting this value to the LiveData.

I would appreciate if someone can help with. Thanks.

Comment: can you share your setValue() method please

Comment: @RishabhJain This expanded lambda                                                             
 disposable.add(userRepository.getUser()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(value -> userLiveData.setValue(value), Throwable::printStackTrace));

Comment: Did u define the observer? Where is the onChang function? Check this: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#observe_livedata_objects

Comment: Maybe disposable is already disposed? Can you show the dispose logic for your `disposable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take look at paragraph ["Observe LiveData objects"](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#observe_livedata_objects):

> Generally, LiveData **delivers updates only when data changes**, and only to active observers. An exception to this behavior is that observers also receive an update when they change from an inactive to an active state. Furthermore, if the observer changes from inactive to active a second time, it only receives an update if the value has changed since the last time it became active.

I in your case, viewmodel lives as long as activity is in backstack. It lead to `LiveData` hold instance of `UserEntry` and when you come back to this activity and call `loadUserEntry()` it load equal (or even same) instance of `UserEntry`. Loaded instance is equal to previous one -> `LiveData` doesn't redeliver it.

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer. I changed method from setValue to postValue. The problem was in wrong method.
setValue():
Sets the value. If there are active observers, the value will be dispatched to them. This method must be called from the main thread.

Comment: If you update multiple times `LiveData` after `onPause()`, then wen `onResume()` is called  (when you return to your `Activity`) - you'll get only the latest value so you will lose other velues. This is very important to know!